# Path error on Atlassian Bamboo SSH deployment to Heroku

Tags: git, heroku, ssh, bitbucket, bamboo

Hi: I'm trying something I think should be pretty simple -- pushing the contents of a node.js Bitbucket repository to Heroku using Bamboo. The CI plan is triggered when I push from the local repository to Bitbucket, and then it triggers the Bamboo Deployment task. Since the Heroku plug-in for Bamboo *only* works with a Java WAR file, I've opted for the SSH task, and used the two git CLI-commands:

git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
git push git@heroku.com:rewindpoloonline.git

However, when I (manually) try the Deployment plan, I get the following error:

```
Starting task 'Push Rewind Polo Online Source to Heroku' of type    'com.atlassian.bamboo.plugins.bamboo-scp-plugin:sshtask'
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    Connecting to heroku.com on port: 22
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    Executing [
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38     git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    git push git@heroku.com:rewindpoloonline.git master
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    ]
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38     !  Invalid path.
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38     !  Syntax is: git@heroku.com:<app>.git where <app> is your app's name.
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    [
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38     git config --global url.ssh://git@heroku.com/.insteadOf https://git.heroku.com/
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    git push git@heroku.com:rewindpoloonline.git master
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    ] has finished.
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    Result: exit code = 1
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    SSH command failed. Failing build.
24-Jan-2015 09:39:38    Finished task 'Push Rewind Polo Online Source to Heroku' with result: Failed
```

This all works if I use the same git CLI-commands from terminal (Mac OS X 10.1) which confirms (in my mind) that the SSH key (with passcode) has been properly deployed to Heroku.